# Travis CI: apt-get installs one version of Firefox, firefox executable is still another?

Tags: 14.04, apt, firefox

14.04.5 LTS.

I need Firefox >=48 for my Travis build: https://travis-ci.org/umts/incidents/builds/240872628

So I `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install firefox`, which says:

```
Unpacking firefox (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
```

etc.

But then my automated tests were failing with the same exact message as when I had the built-in version of firefox (38.4.0esr). So as a sanity check, I added `firefox -v` *after* the install, which returns:

```
(process:5877): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 38.4.0
```

Perhaps that failed C assertion is meaningful here? But on the face of it,  apt is installing one version of a package, but then using that package gives me a much older version, despite apt having returned no error messages.

How can I successfully install and use Firefox >=48 in this context?

Comment: What is the output of `whereis firefox | tr ' ' '\n' | grep  bin`?

Comment: /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/bin/X11/firefox
/usr/local/bin/firefox

Comment: the out put of `which firefox` and `dpkg -S $(which firefox)`

Comment: `which firefox` /usr/local/bin/firefox
`dpkg -S $(which firefox)` dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Travis CI, Firefox is pre-installed at `/usr/bin/X11/firefox`, which seems to be the build geckodriver was using, regardless of whether I used `update-alternatives` to specify which one I wanted.

So I started my build with:

```
whereis firefox | tr ' ' '\n' | grep bin | xargs sudo rm
```

to remove all existing versions of firefox. Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install firefox` as in my question. [This worked](https://travis-ci.org/umts/incidents/builds/240904454).

Thanks Ravexina for your debugging help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have two version of Firefox installed on your Ubuntu.

one which has been installed using package manager is located at:

```
/usr/bin/firefox
```

the other which your system is using (I guess you installed it somehow manually) is located at:

```
/usr/local/bin/firefox
```

use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

to set the `/usr/bin/firefox` as your default browser. you can also run it using absolute path like `/usr/bin/firefox`, for example to see the version of firefox:

```
/usr/bin/firefox -v
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this is an automated Travis build,  so I'd want `sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /usr/bin/firefox` to avoid interactive mode. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by piping one of your debugging commands: `whereis firefox | tr ' ' '\n' | grep bin` to `xargs sudo rm` before installing the correct Firefox. This did it.

Comment: It wasn't a good thing to do ;)

Comment: If you have a better solution than removing existing versions of Firefox, I'm certainly happy to accept them.